# How do I disagree with a flag?

Tags: support

Processing my review queue, I found that I was asked to evaluate someone elses flag that a given answer was "not an answer".

If I agree, I hit the "flag or disagree" button, and click accept.
I don't see a button to disagree with the flag.

(I'm intentionally not listing which answer because I don't want to distract)

Comment: After you click "flag or disagree", look for the "it has invalid  flags" option.

Comment: I do not have an "invalid flags" option. (UPDATE: if I open in an incognito window, I do have that option. Must be a problem on my side.)

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace so, does that resolve the issue for you?

Comment: It doesn't resolve the issue, but it does strongly imply that it is my problemand that I'm going to have to find the solution on my own.  I'm going to leave the question open and if I find the answer, I'll update here.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Try disabling any user scripts you might be running, one of them might be interfering with the flagging dialog.